# Is there a way that I can program a command line game that would work on both Windows and Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, c++11

I am currently working on a space invaders game in C++. I am trying to figure out a way to use only the standard library to create this game so that I can run it on Windows and Linux and get the same result.

So my question is this, can you program a console game in C++ using only the standard library that when compiled will run on both Windows and Linux?

Comment: What you can do is branch the graphics logic based on the operating system. For instance you could create a graphics objects based on OS type. **#ifdef __linux__ gfx=LinuxGfx() #elif _WIN32 gfx = Win32Gfx()** or something of the sort

Comment: `Is there a way that I can program a command line game that would work on both Windows and Linux?` Yes. `using only the standard library` No.

Comment: Yes you can. But it depends on how sophisticated you want the game to be. The more sophisticated, the less likely to find a portable solution using only the standard libraries.

Comment: @devdoesit Are you sure you want to neglect libraries that are available cross-platform?

Comment: @Swordfish I have to for my software design class. I said the same exact thing

Answer (score 4):

Easily, no.

There are terminal control codes, some of which are both supported under Windows, and UNIX.

- Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences
- UNIX(ish): http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes

There is some commonality and cross-over between the two.  This would be a lot of work, and while I would be the first to admire such a work, I would doubt it would work well.

You're probably better off spending your time using something like the [SDL library](https://www.libsdl.org/) for cross-platform support.  Maybe use SDL to make it *look like* a terminal, if that's a core requirement.

Even under various UNIX flavours (and terminals) the escape codes vary.  The ncurses library hides a lot of this complexity.

Comment: @Joshua - I'm pretty sure there used to be some kind of escape sequence support in older versions of Windows (maybe not a full set?) ... I have some vague memories of having to use them.

Comment: BSD Unix had a terminal-based Space Invaders game in the 1980s. It wasn't very challenging below 9600 bps, but that shouldn't be a problem now. You might as well stick to the ANSI escape sequences, chances that anyone will attach a VT52 to a modern system are pretty low.

Comment: @Kingsley ANSI.SYS maybe? I don't think it was enabled by default, though.

Answer (score 2):

No. The C and C++ standard libraries do not contain any functions which perform any of the following tasks, all of which are critical for graphical console applications:

- Clear the terminal
- Get the size of the terminal (in rows and columns)
- Move the terminal cursor to a specific position

On Windows systems, these functions are available as part of the [Console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions). This API is Windows-specific, and is not usable on non-Windows systems.

On Linux and other UNIX systems, these functions are implemented within terminal emulators, and are often accessed using the [ncurses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/) library. This library is not available on Windows outside of non-native environments like Cygwin.

Comment: The OP could use a complex system of ANSI escape codes.  These can be supported in both Windows and UNIX terminals.

Comment: Better recommend [PDCurses](https://pdcurses.sourceforge.io/) over ncurses.

Comment: @Kingsley Maybe? I recall that having some limitations, although perhaps Windows 10 has improved it somewhat.

Comment: @Swordfish That starts getting into the realm of nonstandard libraries, which isn't what the OP was asking for. While ncurses isn't part of the C / C++ standard libraries either, it's at least provided on most UNIX systems.